# Как вызвать не статическую переменную из статического метода?

Tags: java

Случай не совсем стандартный: установил я Linux на телефон, а в Linux - Eclipse. Попробовал написать простую программу, но тут мне выдало ошибку! Почему компилятор требует сделать переменную статической, а когда я делаю переменную - еще и метод? Раньше, вроде, все нормально работало. Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello_World {
    String str;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = sc.nextLine();

        showString(str);
    }

    void showString(String str) {
        for (int i=1; i==100; i++)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

А вот ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field str
>       Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field str 
>   at Hello_World.main(Hello_World.java:8)

P.S. Если нужно:

Версия JDK: 1.7.0_60

Версия Eclipse: 3.8.0

ОС: Debian Wheeze

Comment: А не забыли ли вы случайно создать экземпляр объекта? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Дело не в операционной системе, а в устройстве JVM. Статические переменные инициализируются, когда класс загружается в виртуальную машину. А не статические переменные инициализируются только тогда, когда создаётся объект класса. Не создав объект класса, вы не можете обращаться к его не статической переменной по той простой причине, что её не существует.

Но вы можете создать объект класса

```
Hello_World hello = new Hello_World();
```

и уже потом обратиться к переменной:

```
hello.str = sc.nextLine();
```

и методу:

```
hello.showString(hello.str);
```

В этом случае, ваша не статическая переменная `str` инициализируется, при создании объекта и будет доступна из статического метода.

---

Кроме этого хотелось бы выделить ошибку в цикле `for`.

```
for (int i=1; i==100; i++)
               ^^
```

Структура цикла такова

```
for (инициализация ; условие продолжения цикла ; изменение)
```

Когда `условие продолжения цикла` принимает булево значение `false`, цикл прерывается. В вашем случае, при первой же проверке, условие возвращает `false`, так как `i=1` и `1!=100`.

Вероятно, вы хотели 100 раз вывести на экран то, что было введено с клавиатуры:

```
for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
```

Comment: Ужас! Я со своим Android'ом совсем отупел... :) Привык переменные засовывать за метод `onCreate `, методы делать нестатическими, даже забыл как цикл писать! Спасибо :D!

Comment: Когда `условие выхода из цикла` принимает булево значение `false`, цикл прерывается, может тогда стоит его назвать условием **продолжения** цикла?

Comment: @sercxjo, сейчас прочитал в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#.D0.A6.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BB_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BC) про это. Никогда не понимал таких деталей терминологии. Но для красоты изменил ответ. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы обращаетесь из статичного контекста к нестатичному. Сделайте функцию showString статичной.

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё главное действие вынести в отдельный метод `go()` и запускать его через создание объекта класса `Hello_World`.

```
package start;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello_World {
    String str;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Hello_World().go();
    }

    void showString(String str) {
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
            System.out.println(str);
    }

    private void go() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = sc.nextLine();

        showString(str);
    }
}
```