# Использование модификатора static для метода в Java

Tags: java, методы

Нашел информацию о модификаторах в Java. Прочитал, что модификатор static может использоваться для метода чтобы не "привязывать" этот метод к конкретному объекту класса, а значит, для использования данного метода не стоит создавать объект этого метода. Что это означает и в каких случаях это полезно?

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/456150) есть частичный ответ на ваш вопрос. А на вопрос "зачем?" можно отвечать долго. Вся библиотека `Math` состоит из статических методов. А зачем создавать объект каждый раз, когда нужен метод оттуда?

Comment: Да уж, все было довольно просто. Спасибо

Comment: Удалите вопрос, если он перестал быть актуальным.

Comment: LEQUADA, все же один момент остался неясным. Скажите, пожалуйста, тогда как понять, какая разница между public и static?

Comment: О, это совершенно разные вещи. Если переменная или метод имеют модификатор `public`, то вы можете к ним обратиться напрямую, при условии, что создадите объект класса. `static` элементы все доступны  сразу после загрузки в JVM. Даже не нужно создавать объект. Это не единственная их разница. Во всех книжках по Java для начинающих об этом рассказывают довольно подробно.

Comment: `static` методы обычно выполняют некие операции над данными, не привязываясь к внутреннему состоянию. Как вам уже привели, пример, почти все методы библиотеки Math, потому что вычисление синуса(и косинуса и т.д.) не привязано к внутреннему состоянию, а основывается только на входных данных.

Comment: Спасибо, так яснее

Comment: public (private, protected) это описатели области видимости имен и static не имеет к ним никакого отношения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` методы полезны, когда какое-то действие константно вне зависимости от уникальности данных экземпляра класса. 
К примеру, класс `Thread` имеет метод `currentThread()`, который возвращает поток, из которого вызвался этот метод. Он является статическим, потому что сколько не создавай экземпляров `Thread` и сколько там не пихай `Runnable`, на текущий поток это никак не повлияет. 
А вообще, не грузись, со временем, все станет на свои места

Comment: Неудачный какой-то пример. Если у человека возник такой вопрос, вполне логично предположить, что он не имел дела с потоками.

Comment: Чесно говоря, ещё не имел с ними дела(

Comment: @muscled-boy, ну, хорошо, тогда есть класс АлфавитыВсехЯзыковМира, который будет содержать все алфавиты, включая русский, то все методы, возвращающие различные алфавиты, будут статическими, потому что сколько бы не добавлялось новых языков в мире, русский алфавит и другие будет неизменными

А вообще, друг, не парься, когда тебе реально понадобятся статические методы, ты поймешь их надобность))

Comment: leqada :D нужно надеяться на чудо)

Comment: И Вам тоже спасибо